# Cite/Reference OpenMP in a Paper

Tags: c++, openmp, citations

I am writing a paper and implemented an algorithm using OpenMP. Since Visual Studio directly supports OpenMP, am I required to cite OpenMP in my paper?

Comment: Perhaps better asked the one you are submitting the paper to.

Comment: For any other libraries, I usually provide a reference to the website.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing a paper and not directly about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about how to reference a paper.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.  Maybe belongs on [academia.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would cite it if only for clarity about the version used, and to point the reader to more information.   My suggestion would be to cite the API reference for the [OpenMP specification](http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications/) of the appropriate version, using whatever style your journal uses for citing manuals or technical reports.

If you don't know what version of OpenMP you are using, the following program:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("OpenMP version: %d\n", _OPENMP);
    return 0;
}
```

When run like:

```
$ g++ openmpversion.cpp -fopenmp
$ ./a.out
```

will report `200505` for 2.5, `200805` for 3.0, and `201307` for 4.0.

Comment: @authors, Please edit something in the answer. I have accidentally downvoted instead of an upvoting and now my vote has been locked. I want to upvote this answer.

Answer (score 12):

I guess you must have decided one way or the other by now, but, for the record, YES, I think you should definitely cite OpenMP, by citing the specification document for the version you are using.  For instance, if you are using OpenMP 3.0 (2008), your BibTeX entry would look like this:

```
@misc{ openmp08,
    author = {{OpenMP Architecture Review Board}},
    title = {{OpenMP} Application Program Interface Version 3.0},
    month = may,
    year = 2008,
    url = {http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/spec30.pdf}
}
```

Comment: the line `url = {\url{http://...}}` will cause an infinite loop in the hyperref package, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24647/71379. It should be changed to `url = {http://...}`

Answer (score 7):

Bibtex entry for the paper (Dagum, Leonardo, and Ramesh Menon. "OpenMP: an industry standard API for shared-memory programming.") mentioned by Ame is:

```
@article{dagum1998openmp,
    Author = {Dagum, Leonardo and Menon, Ramesh},
    Date-Added = {2014-07-24 11:13:01 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-07-24 11:13:01 +0000},
    Journal = {Computational Science \& Engineering, IEEE},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {46--55},
    Publisher = {IEEE},
    Title = {OpenMP: an industry standard API for shared-memory programming},
    Volume = {5},
    Year = {1998}}
```

This is the paper that is normally cited for OpenMP as a concept.

Comment: However, this is quite old and really serves when there is some legal need to cite something, than to really point to an up to date resource.

Comment: OpenMP 2.0 as provided in Visual Studio isn't much more up to date than that reference.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are referring to technical details of a specific API version, you probably want to cite the following paper:
Dagum, Leonardo, and Ramesh Menon. "OpenMP: an industry standard API for shared-memory programming." Computational Science & Engineering, IEEE 5.1 (1998): 46-55.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are required to (better ask you lawyer or the one you commit to), but you may refer to the official OpenMP specifications: http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications/